# Sending text file name from command line c++

Tags: c++, file, c++11, command-line

I want to run my code and send my file in 2 ways

1. `myprogram < input.txt` or `cat input.txt | myprogram`
2. `myprogram input.txt`

I have figured out the secong way using `argc` and `argv[]` but I am not able to figure out how to write the code for the first option.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
     ifstream fin;
     if(argc > 1){

        fin.open (argv[1]);
     }
     else
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use the pipe operator in your code? Or are you asking about how to write to input.txt with the > operator? [Do note that `>` is a special character](https://quickleft.com/blog/command-line-tutorials-redirection-pipes/)

Comment: You mean `myprogram < input.txt` and `myprogram input.txt`. Using `myprogram > input.txt` writes to `input.txt`

Comment: Yes myprogram < input.txt

Comment: Contents of input.txt   - Add Veronica Add Sam Delete Sam. I am procesing each word and further validating it

Comment: You have a couple of choices, a non-portable Linux solution is just to open `"/dev/stdin"` if no argument is given. A portable solution would require passing `std::cin` as an `istream` reference and reading within a function if no argument was given.

Comment: How should I implement passing cin as an istream reference ?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned above in the comment, a portable way is passing either the open file or `std::cin` as an `istream` reference to a function and doing your input there. In that case either the file or `std::cin` may be passed. E.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void readinfo (std::istream& in)
{
    std::string s;
    while (in >> s)
        std::cout << s << '\n';
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc > 1) {     /* read from file if given as argument */
        std::ifstream fin (argv[1]);
        if (fin.is_open())
            readinfo (fin);
        else {
            std::cerr << "error: file open failed.\n";
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else {  /* read from stdin */
        readinfo (std::cin);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A non-portable Linux only option reading from `/dev/stdin` if no file is given simply requires a *ternary* operator, e.g.

```
    std::ifstream fin (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "/dev/stdin");
    if (!fin.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "error: file open failed.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    /* read from fin here */
```

Neither are completely elegant, but both support (subject to the OS constraint)

```
myprogram < input.txt
```

or

```
myprogram input.txt
```

Comment: Got it ! Thank you so much

Comment: Good, glad it helped. Good luck with your coding.

Comment: @KumudaAggarwal You should change the original question to `myprogram < input.txt` and then accept Davids answer.

Answer (score -2):

You want to read from stdin, and for that there's 2 options:

- `std::cin`
- `fread()` and other C-style IO

`std::cin >>` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin has the advantage of reading formatted text into some binary representation https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

C-style IO https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c has the advantage of reading binary data well.

It depends on what you want to do with it your input

Comment: In else block { cin>> s; fin.open(s) }

Comment: Is this what you mean ?

Comment: So stdin is already a file, hence you don't need to open it, you can just read from it. And basically there's two ways of doing that. The c++ way is to use std::cin's stream operator (`>>`) or to use c's `fread` (and `fetgs`, `fgetc`, etc.) using the `stdin` (no namespace) macro _as_ the `FILE *` argument